# Making a button into a changing image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to mimic a project I found on codepen:
http://codepen.io/ChynoDeluxe/pen/pJxOQE/

At this point I can create the list items and delete them, but I want to turn the delete button into an image that will increase in opacity when hovered over. However I can't figure out how to make the created button into an image. Ideally I would figure out how to make it the same trash can icon, but I'm hoping to make the picture appear then I can go from there.

I tried making the picture the background image but it didn't show up properly. Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTPYE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>MSL List</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style>
    div li input {
                margin-right: 10px;
            }


            #wrapper {
                width: 300px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                font: 1em Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
           }

        #error {
            display: none; 
            background: rgba(237, 28, 36, .7);
            color:#fff;
            padding: 14px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

        #inpt {
            background: rgba(31, 41, 51, .9);
            color: #fff;
            padding: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: .9em;
            width: 227px;
            border: none;​
        }

        #btn {  
            background: #0066cc;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 1.75em;
            border: none;
            padding: 6px;
            width: 45px;
        }

        input, button {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        input, button:focus {
            outline:none;
        }

        #iList {
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color: #fff;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }   

        li {
            border-top: #E6E6E6 solid 1px;
            padding: 12px;
        }   

        .removeBtn {
            float: right;
            padding: 4px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            background-image:url("recycle.png");
            opacity:.6;     
        }
  </style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#E6E6E6">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="error">Please enter an item!</div>
    <div id="form-head">
      <input type="text" id="inpt" placeholder="What are you looking for?" /><button id="btn">+</button>
    </div>
    <div id="iList">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function updateItemStatus() {  //making the function that updates whether an item should have a line through it or not
          var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");  //used to replace "cb_" with "" to remove the _cb part of the string on the focus
          var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);  //gets element (item_minSecMsec)
          if (this.checked) {  //if an item is checked, bugged
            itemText.style.opacity = .25;
            itemText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
          } else {
            itemText.style.opacity = 1;
            itemText.style.textDecoration = "none";
          }
        };

        function deleteItem() {var dbId = this.id.replace("btn_", "");
            var delBtn = document.getElementById("li_" + dbId);  
                delBtn.onclick=function() {
                this.parentNode.removeChild(delBtn);
                return false;
            };
        }

        function addNewItem(iList, itemText) {  //defining a function that acts upon list and itemText to label it with a time stamp
          var date = new Date(); //sets date ia variable that sets date to make the time stamp
          var id = date.getMilliseconds(); //makes id = milliseconds
          var listItem = document.createElement("li"); //creates a list element node
          listItem.id = "li_" + id; //gives that node an id of li_minSecMsec

          var checkBox = document.createElement("input"); //creates an input node
          checkBox.type = "checkbox"; //gives that input node a type of checkbox
          checkBox.id = "cb_" + id; //makes the checkbox id cb_minSecMsec
          checkBox.onclick = updateItemStatus; //when the checkbox is clicked it runs updateItemStatus function defined above

          var span = document.createElement("span"); //creates a span node. 
          span.id = "item_" + id; //makes span id = item_minSecMsec
          span.innerHTML = itemText; //makes the inner text of the span node itemText (which has no further value in this function)

          var delBtn = document.createElement("button");
          delBtn.setAttribute("class", "removeBtn");
          delBtn.id = "btn_" + id;
          delBtn.onclick = deleteItem;

          listItem.appendChild(checkBox); //append checkbox node to the li node created
          listItem.appendChild(span);     //append the span node to the li node as well
          listItem.appendChild(delBtn);
          iList.appendChild(listItem); //add the li node to list parameter (presumably any list in the DOM?)

          document.getElementById("inpt").value="";
        }

        var inItemText = document.getElementById("inpt"); //gets the input text
        inItemText.focus(); //makes it the focus


        document.getElementById("inpt") //makes enter button run it as if btn was clicked
            .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                document.getElementById("btn").click();
            }
        });

        var btnNew = document.getElementById("btn"); //gets button
        btnNew.onclick = function() { //on click the button runs a function that runs the addNewItem function
            if (document.getElementById("inpt").value.length < 1) {
                document.getElementById("error").style.display="block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("error").style.display="none";
                var inItemText = document.getElementById("inpt"); //defines inItemText within the function as the input text
                var itemText = inItemText.value; //makes new variable of itemText to get the value of what is in the input
                addNewItem(document.getElementById("iList"), itemText); //this is where the li node is added to the ul and itemText is set as the text in the input
            }
        };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[Here's how it shows up where the pic should be the buttons on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwEu3.png)

Comment: The button element has some default stylings, did you try overriding them first?

Comment: why not simply change the text color instead of the opacity. Also, there's nothing stopping you from changing the button's opacity with hover.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, only tested on Firefox right now, but it should work across all browsers:

```
 .removeBtn {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    float: right;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image:url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/trash_recyclebin_empty_closed.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity:.6;  
    filter: alpha(opacity=60) /*For IE*/
}

.removeBtn:hover {
   height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    float: right;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image:url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/trash_recyclebin_empty_closed.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity:1;  
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) /*For IE*/
}
```

You can change the size of the icon by changing the width and height sizes and the icon should scale. I randomly grabbed that image from Google just for testing, so just replace the URL with your own path :)